# CSS-File of a GWT-UIBinder not responding to @media max-width

Tags: css, gwt, media, uibinder

I'm using an UIBinder in a GWT-Project and have an external .css file via

```
  <ui:style src="NavPage.css" />
```

In which I want to use a different style for mobile systems, but if I put

`@media all and (min-width: 460px{ xxx}`

It doesn't change anything, I've played around with 1px, 100px, max-width of 3000px non of those trigger my styles in there. (Neither does min/max-device-width)

But this does

`@media all { xxx}`

Any idea on why my css file can't use Screen-width?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CssResource` in GWT is limited to CSS 2 (plus a few additions).

If you want full CSS3 support, switch to [`GssResource`](https://github.com/jdramaix/gss.gwt); it'll be bundled in the next GWT version (2.7) and will replace `CssResource` in the version after that. The syntax is a bit different but there's a tool to convert `CssResource`-style stylesheets to the `GssResource` syntax.

See also [the presentation at the last GWT Meet-Up](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1iKL3iTQPdt4i9838hvnr6SrYl92ftkNdNRPs08sGUO0/pub)

Comment: Thanks for the help, I've got another question: Can I define my .css file somewhere else, like in the index.html, with the standard `<link>` ? Because then it would be easier to just define another .css file there for a mobile version

Comment: Or do you have any other advise on handling mobile support with uibinders?